# What is eclipse using to determine that it can or can't build a maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

What tool or file is eclipse using to determine that it can or can't build a project?

The project is imported to Eclipse Luna as a Maven project, and Eclipse has the Maven Plugin and some m2e connectors; it seems to be happily pulling jars into the maven repo.  Coming from a Visual Studio background, and somewhat new to the Eclipse paradigm, my understanding is that the purpose of the pom.xml file is to define the build process and dependencies, and that maven is the agent which produces said dependencies, but not the actual compiler which is still javac.  Does Eclipse hve another project file somewhere?

The specific issue triggering my question is this:
I'm using Java Oracle JDK 1.7 (mandated by customer). I am including a lib (theParent) which has its own dependencies (theGrandParents), Hadoop among other things. That version of Hadoop pulled in as a grandparent dependency requires some jdk1.6 tools (the GreatGrandParents).

Becase Java 1.6 is not on the build path (using 1.7!), and the dependency chain actually specifies a version, Eclipse is refusing to build the project.  I'm about 95% certain I'm not using any functionality of any of the ancestors which would cause it to actually load those modules.   At least in a sanity check test, Maven will build-and-run the project as is without exceptions. This is true through eclipse (Maven -> RunAs -> Maven Build) and the command line.

So:

1. What does Eclipse Luna use to build a Maven project, if not Maven?
2. Does Java play nicely with itself? What is the risk from pulling in the older tools to satisfy the dependency?

Comment: I would say it's the pom.xml file.

Comment: @JoeInner - Is Eclipse interpreting the pom independently, then?  Otherwise, why the different behaviors from maven directly and through Eclipse?